# How do you switch rows and columns in SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, pivot

I've seen many rows-to-columns threads here but can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

How do you convert the following table:

```
ID    Foo    Bar
1     A      F
2     B      G
3     C      H
4     D      I
5     E      J
```

Into this:

```
ID    1    2    3    4    5
Foo   A    B    C    D    E
Bar   F    G    H    I    J
```

Thanks! I am using SQL Server 2005 by the way.

Comment: You can do an `UNPIVOT` followed by a `PIVOT`, but as always, it will only work for a fixed size. And, as always, the question has to be asked: why are you doing report formatting in SQL? Rows and Columns are *not the same things* in SQL.

Comment: I've done it using pivot if there were only 2 columns in the original table. But for 3 (or more columns) I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm pretty new at SQL... Where should I be doing the formatting?

Comment: @OjRaqueño - In the user application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is *an* answer. As I alluded to in my comment, this only works in the dimensions that you're working with are known/fixed. First, the sample data:

```
declare @Table table (ID int not null,Foo char(1) not null,Bar char(1) not null)
insert into @Table (ID,Foo,Bar)
select 1,'A','F' union all
select 2,'B','G' union all
select 3,'C','H' union all
select 4,'D','I' union all
select 5,'E','J'

select * from @Table --As per your original data table

;with Rot1 as (
    select
        *
    from
        @Table unpivot (Value for Col in (Foo,Bar)) t
)
select * from Rot1 -- See below

;with Rot1 as (
    select
        *
    from
        @Table unpivot (Value for Col in (Foo,Bar)) t
), Rot2 as (
    select
        *
    from Rot1 pivot (MAX(Value) for ID in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) t
)
select * from Rot2 -- As per your required result
```

The output when merely selecting from `Rot1` is:

```
ID  Value   Col
1   A   Foo
1   F   Bar
2   B   Foo
2   G   Bar
3   C   Foo
3   H   Bar
4   D   Foo
4   I   Bar
5   E   Foo
5   J   Bar
```

So, we can construct this query, so long as we know *all* of the cross-referencing identifiers, e.g. `Foo`, `Bar`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5`. In most cases of wanting to do this kind of transform, you don't know all of these values, and so SQL isn't the way to achieve the transform - use whatever tool is consuming the original results to achieve this kind of reformatting.